# GWT Highcharts Donut Pie Chart

Tags: gwt, highcharts, pie-chart, donut-chart, gwt-highcharts

I have recently discovered highcharts and am practicing with them, but I cannot find any in depth tutorials on highcharts using gwt out there. I've looked everywhere and they all seem to be in javascript. I have looked at the moxie site, but I really would like more than that. Particularly when it comes to designing a donut pie chart. I am having trouble designing one and there are no gwt examples out there. So does anyone know of a good tutorial for highcharts and also how to make a donut chart using gwt?

I got a really basic pie chart, but I have no idea how to continue on and create a donut pie chart, where there is an outer ring and an inner circle.

```
   public void onLoad(){


Chart chart = new Chart()
    .setType(Series.Type.PIE)
    .setChartTitleText("Internet Usage")
    .setMarginRight(10)
    .setPiePlotOptions(new PiePlotOptions()
            .setInnerSize(200));


    Series series = chart.createSeries()
            .setName("Internets")
            .setPoints(new Point[]{
                    new Point("FireFox", 45.0),
                    new Point("IE", 26.8),
                    new Point("Chrome", 12.8),  
                    new Point("Safari", 8.5),
                    new Point("Opera", 6.2),
                    new Point("Others", 0.7)

        });

    chart.addSeries(series);
    thisPanel.add(chart);       }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Try to set innerSize this way: `piePlotOptions.setOption("innerSize", 200);`

Comment: I am not trying to just create an inner circle, but to place another graph with different data in the inside circle much like this:http://i.stack.imgur.com/80Xr4.png

Comment: Sorry, I have missed somehow that notification. Thanks for clarifying!  In that case use `chart.createSeries().setPlotOptions(PlotOptions)` so there you can set `setInnerSize` to 0 and `setSize` to previous inner size.